# Magento 2.3.2 Collection foreach didn't get disabled product

Tags: filter, product-collection, magento2.3.2, disabled-products

I am using Magento 2.3.2. I am filtering collection if product ids found in array. before foreach if I am printing collection I am getting data. But in foreach I am not getting any data.

```
$productIds = array(123,124); // product ids
$productCollection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect("*")->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array("in" => $productIds));

echo "<pre>";
echo "#########################################";
print_r($productCollection->getData());
echo "#########################################";

foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getData());
}
```

Below values I am getting result of first print

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 23947
            [entity_id] => 23908
            [created_in] => 1
            [updated_in] => 2147483647
            [attribute_set_id] => 22
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => test123
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2018-11-10 17:03:23
            [updated_at] => 2019-08-23 06:30:15
            [status] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [row_id] => 70562
            [entity_id] => 69713
            [created_in] => 1
            [updated_in] => 2147483647
            [attribute_set_id] => 19
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => firstprod
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2019-03-21 20:45:31
            [updated_at] => 2019-08-25 08:30:50
            [status] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to set flag after collection to get disable products from collection object like below

```
$productCollection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection();
$productCollection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
  print_r($product->getData();
}
```

**can you pls try once like below** ,

```
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
  echo $product->getId();
}
```

**or if you still want to display data, there is a syntax error in your code,**

pls try below code,

```
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
   print_r($product->getData());
}
```

Comment: This is also not working

Comment: @PrashantValanda, what about, echo $product->getId();

Comment: I am not getting Id as well, because its skip disable products

Comment: @PrashantValanda, then add filter to your collection as like below,
->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in'=>array(1,2)))

Comment: I have also tried that is also not working

Comment: what is printing in first print_r? can you pls post in question pls..

Comment: updated question

Comment: @PrashantValanda, Same code is working well in my end, pls try to enable display errors and check is there any errors?